# Generically adding implicits to both TreeSet and TreeMaps

Tags: scala, scala-collections, scala-implicits

I want to add some helpful implicits to both mutable and immutable TreeMaps and TreeSets in Scala.

Here is my attempt:

1. First try to define the least upper bound of TreeMap and TreeSet that has `headOption`/`lastOption` (from `GenTraversableLike`) and `from`/`to`/`until` (from `Sorted`):

   ```
     type SortedCollection[A, Repr <: SortedCollection[A, Repr]] = collection.generic.Sorted[A, Repr] with collection.GenTraversableLike[A, Repr]
   ```
2. Write my util:

   ```
   implicit class RichSortedCollection[A, Repr <: SortedCollection[A, Repr]](s: SortedCollection[A, Repr]) {
     def greaterThanOrEqualTo(a: A): Option[A] = s.from(a).headOption
     def lessThan(a: A): Option[A] = s.until(a).lastOption
     def lessThanOrEqualTo(a: A): Option[A] = s.to(a).lastOption
   }
   ```

This only works partially: `SortedSet#greaterThan` compiles but `TreeMap#greaterThan` does not. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

`TreeMap[A, B]` (transitively) extends `GenTraversableLike[(A, B), TreeMap[A, B]]` and `Sorted[A, TreeMap[A, B]]`, so you could say it's a:

```
Sorted[A, TreeMap[A, B]] with GenTraversableLike[(A, B), TreeMap[A, B]]
```

This is *close* to your type alias, but the first type parameter of `Sorted` and `GenTraverableLike` in the type alias `SortedCollection` must be the same, which they are not above. They simply aren't compatible. That is, `Repr = TreeMap[A, B]` is fine, but `A = (A, B)` doesn't make sense.

You're going to have the same issue with all map types, and your only real choice is to re-implement `RichSortedCollection` for maps as well.